# AWK to print field $2 first, then field $1

Tags: unix, awk

Here is the input(sample):

```
name1@gmail.com|com.emailclient.account
name2@msn.com|com.socialsite.auth.account
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
Emailclient name1@gmail.com
Socialsite name2@msn.com
```

If I use AWK like this:

```
cat foo | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {print $2 " " $1}'
```

it messes up the output by overlaying field 1 on the top of field 2.

Any tips/suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A couple of general tips *(besides the DOS line ending issue)*:

`cat` is for concatenating files, it's not the only tool that can read files! If a command doesn't read files then use redirection like `command < file`.

You can set the field separator with the `-F` option so instead of:

```
cat foo | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {print $2 " " $1}'
```

Try:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $2" "$1}' foo
```

This will output:

```
com.emailclient.account name1@gmail.com
com.socialsite.auth.accoun name2@msn.com
```

To get the desired output you could do a variety of things. I'd probably `split()` the second field:

```
awk -F'|' '{split($2,a,".");print a[2]" "$1}' file
emailclient name1@gmail.com
socialsite name2@msn.com
```

Finally to get the first character converted to uppercase is a bit of a pain in `awk` as you don't have a nice built in `ucfirst()` function:

```
awk -F'|' '{split($2,a,".");print toupper(substr(a[2],1,1)) substr(a[2],2),$1}' file
Emailclient name1@gmail.com
Socialsite name2@msn.com
```

If you want something more concise *(although you give up a sub-process)* you could do:

```
awk -F'|' '{split($2,a,".");print a[2]" "$1}' file | sed 's/^./\U&/'
Emailclient name1@gmail.com
Socialsite name2@msn.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe your file contains CRLF terminator. Every lines followed by \r\n.

`awk` recognizes the `$2` actually `$2\r`. The `\r` means goto the start of the line.

`{print $2\r$1}` will print `$2` first, then return to the head, then print `$1`. So the field 2 is overlaid by the field 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, SleepyProgrammer! I recommend you to add more details if you can. This post looks like a comment and might be removed...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip, that was the case when there is only a single column, so I just want to append another column, but `$0` (or `$1`) returns a string ending with `\r` which causes this unexpected behavior of "overlaying" the initial column.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dot or a pipe as the field separator:

```
awk -v FS='[.|]' '{
    printf "%s%s %s.%s\n", toupper(substr($4,1,1)), substr($4,2), $1, $2
}' << END
name1@gmail.com|com.emailclient.account
name2@msn.com|com.socialsite.auth.account
END
```

gives:

```
Emailclient name1@gmail.com
Socialsite name2@msn.com
```

Comment: This was my original thought but what about `.co.uk`, `.cam.ac.uk`, ect.. becomes messy.

Answer (score 2):

The awk is ok.  I'm guessing the file is from a windows system and has a CR (^m ascii 0x0d) on the end of the line.

This will cause the cursor to go to the start of the line after $2.

Use dos2unix or vi with `:se ff=unix` to get rid of the CRs.

Comment: each line ends with 0x0d0a, is that was you meant? Would cutting these hex values solve the issue? Thx

Comment: The 0a is ok, just get rid of the 0d

Comment: Thanks! Adding the following into the pipe sorted the problem: | sed 's/\x0d//g' |