# How to use awk for 2 columns and save it into a variable as one element?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file that looks like this

```
.../proj_1/file1.txt 8 2018-03-14 07:46:01
.../proj_1/file3.txt 3 2018-03-14 07:47:01
.../proj_1/file2.txt 10 2018-03-14 07:45:01
.../file1.txt 2 2018-03-14 07:50:01
```

and I'd like to extract date and time which is in the 3. and 4. column and save it into a variable. (dir_path is the name of the directory and source_file is the file I described above)

```
variable=$(grep "$dir_path/.*" source_file | grep -v "$dir_path/.*/" | awk '/[0-9]/{print ($3 $4)}')
```

My desired output is

```
2018-03-14 07:46:00
2018-03-14 07:47:00
2018-03-14 07:45:01
```

But with this code, the output looks like this

```
2018-03-1407:46:00
2018-03-1407:47:00
2018-03-1407:45:01
```

How do I put the space in between the date and time? Is it even possible? If I but a space into the awk expression, the the time and date is saved in separate elements which is not what I want.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Add a comma between `$3` and `$4`, ie: `awk '/[0-9]/{print ($3, $4)}'`

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
awk '/[0-9]/{print ($3" "$4)}'
```

Works for me:

```
awk '/[0-9]/{print ($3" "$4)}' file1.txt

2018-03-14 07:46:01
2018-03-14 07:47:01
2018-03-14 07:45:01
2018-03-14 07:50:01
```

Useful link: [StackOverflow case: AWK to print field $2 first, then field $1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597666/awk-to-print-field-2-first-then-field-1?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Wow, this works in the terminal but doesn't work inside the script... when I iterate through my variable, the output separates the time and date into different element of my variable

Comment: Most likely due to quotation symbols(") try to use escape characters

Comment: Also you can specify delimiter with -F option as stated by link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597666/awk-to-print-field-2-first-then-field-1?answertab=votes#tab-top